# Using someones input in an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a little JavaScript conversation that's somewhat fixed with different routes, I'm using this so far:

JavaScript:

```
alert("Hello\nFriend... Isnt this creepy?");
alert("Im sorry this is weird isnt it?\nMy name is MAX");
alert("MAX stands for Multipurpose AI Xample\n Sorry for my rude introduction, whats your name?");
alert("AH! A great name for such a lad or lass as your self...");
```

EDIT: I want a way where they enter in there name, and then i can use/refrence there name throughout the code

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Comment: you could just add the input in your alert text `alert("some text " + x + " some more text")`

Comment: you should really try tutorials before you ask questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var username = prompt('MAX stands for Multipurpose AI Xample. Sorry for my rude introduction, what is your name?');
alert('AH! ' + username + ' is a great name for such a lad or lass as yourself...');
```

As long as your "application" is just a continuing combination of `alert` or `prompt` then the `username` variable will continue to be available later on, e.g.

```
alert('I hope you are well today, ' + username + '!');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Learn Javascript first.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
If you want to save the person's name save it as a variable.
if you want to refer to that person's name later add plus symbols to combine variables and strings

ex)  `"hello "+name+"!" == "hello kevin!" //where name="kevin"`

```
var name=prompt("what is your name?","");//javascript will wait until you click enter.  then the variable name will be set to whatever you inputed
alert("hello "+name+"! thats a great name!")//say hello!
```